# Calling function with argument from segue

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, segue

I have a FirstVC with table view with segue to another SecondVC where i pass the name of pressed cell. In SecondVC i have another tableview which i want to populate with data. I have a function called gettingUrls() which is pulling data for my table view:

```
DataService.instance.mainRef.child("Folders").child("\(folderName)").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot: DataSnapshot) in...}
```

where "folderName" is the value from FirstVC. This function is implemented into "pull to refresh feature" and it works great. However when i try to run the function itself in viewDidLoad it keeps crashing the app because of empty folderName value. I just can't understand why at this point the value from segue is available in refresh function and not in viewDidLoad.

Here is the code of segue:

```
let detailVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailVC") as! DetailVC
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailVC, animated: true)
        self.present(detailVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        detailVC.folderName = fileName
```

How can i run the function in viewDidLoad?

Answer (score 0):

You're presenting the `DetailVC`'s view before you've set its `folderName` property. The view has loaded but it doesn't yet have a `folderName` so the program crashes. You should place the line `detailVC.folderName = fileName` before you present the `DetailVC`.

You also don't need both the 2nd and 3rd lines - either present the new view controller or push it onto the navigation stack, not both.

Comment: In what way i can place it before DetailVC is shown? I bet the question is silly but i am new to swift.

Comment: Put it before `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailVC, animated: true)`. That's the line that shows the DetailVC.

Comment: Wow it was that easy! Thank you very much :)

Comment: No problem! Could you accept this answer as the solution since it solved your issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should write code with segues to push viewControllers like following not with `navigationController`

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "Verification") {
            let vc = segue.destination as! MyViewController
            vc.delegate = self
            vc.property = value
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! However, the most important part is still unanswered.

Comment: ` vc.delegate = self ` will do it

Answer (score 0):

So with @haarismuneer help, it was enough to pass the variable before initializing SecondVC:

```
detailVC.folderName = fileName
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailVC, animated: true)
```